# How to Unshelve from TFS without preserving shelveset?

Tags: c#, tfs

I am trying to [Unshelve(String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.unshelve.aspx). But when I call this method it keeps the shelveset on the server.

I would like to Unshelve without preserving the changeset:

[image: unshelve]

How can I do it?

Comment: I don't think you can do it one action. You would normally unshelve and then delete the shelveset as far as I know. There could be change conflicts and so I'm guessing that's why two operations.

Comment: I agree with @MikeCheel Pretty sure it's separated intentionally

Comment: I'm thinking because the whole operation would fail if you don't resolve change conflicts in the gui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For further reference

```
Workspace.Unshelve(shelveName, versionControlServer.AuthorizedUser);
versionControlServer.DeleteShelveset(shelveName);
```